# How create a new map from the values in an existing map

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, functional-interface

Having the next original map:

```
G1=[7,8,45,6,9]
G2=[3,9,34,2,1,65]
G3=[6,5,9,1,67,5]
```

Where G1, G2 and G3 are groups of people's ages, How can I create a new map like this:

```
45=[7,8,45,6,9]
65=[3,9,34,2,1,65]
67=[6,5,9,1,67,5]
```

Where the new keys are the max people's age in each group.

I have tried this:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> newMap = originalMap.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Collections.max(x -> x.getValue()), x -> x.getValue()));
```

But the compiler say me: "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface" in this fragment of code:

```
Collections.max(x -> x.getValue())
```

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toMap consumes function for it's `keyMapper` and `valueMapper`. You're doing this correctly for the `valueMapper` in your code but not for the `keyMapper` thus you need to include the `keyMapper` function as follows:

```
originalMap.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .collect(toMap(e -> Collections.max(e.getValue()), Map.Entry::getValue));
```

note the **`e -> Collections.max(e.getValue())`**.

Further, since you're not working with the map keys, you can avoid having to call entrySet() and instead work on the map values:

```
originalMap.values()
           .stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Collections::max, Function.identity()));
```